# Manual download for bibleref-xidx.sty?

Tags: packages

I'm trying to produce a separate index of Bible verses for an article and my problem is that well, I simply get no index. Error message is "File: bibref-xidx.sty not found" so I hope a manual installation should solve it, as it seems not to have been installed with the bibleref package. I can't find a directory from which the files can be downloaded manually.

Any ideas please?

Comment: There is no `bibref-xidx.sty` provided by `bibleref`. There is however a `bibleref-xidx.sty` so perhaps you have simply misspelt the package. A minimal example is needed if that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the contents of `bibleref.tex`, which comes as part of the bibleref bundle on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibleref), you'll see the following lines (modified slightly here):

> %% This is file `sample-xidx.tex', generated with the docstrip utility.
>
> %% The original source files were: bibleref.dtx  (with options: `sample-xidx.tex,package')

And:

> %%  This work consists of the files bibleref.dtx and bibleref.ins and the derived files bibleref-xidx.sty, bibleref.sty, sample-categories.tex, sample-multind.tex, sample-xidx.tex, sample.tex, sample.ist, bibleref.perl.

So, in theory, the .sty file you're looking for should be included by default.  But it isn't.  In order to create it, run:

```
latex bibleref.ins
```

When I did that, one of the files it created was `bibleref-xidx.sty`, which you should put in your TeX tree along wherever `bibleref.sty` is found. And refresh the database with `texhash` or however that's done on Windows and Macs.

Finally, you should probably contact the maintainer of the package, alerting her of your problem. (See the bibleref.pdf for contact information.)

Comment: I had no success trying this, so I'm unsure if I applied your advice correctly as I'm not very experienced with this level of detail. Could you please clarify where this file should be created? Thank you!

Comment: @Lin-- Which step didn't work for you?  (1) If you have the file `bibleref.ins`, (2) you need to run (regular) `latex` on it: open a terminal or command prompt in the directory where the file is and type: `latex bibleref.ins`. (3) This should create the file `bibleref-xidx.sty`.  (4) Find where the file `bibleref.sty` is kept; (5) move the newly created file to the folder where `bibleref.sty` is found. (6) Re-fresh the database (e.g., `sudo texhash` in GNU/Linux; I'm not sure how to do it in other operating systems --- there's probably a button somewhere for it in MikTeX).